# How to Change a size of fragment?

Tags: android, android-layout, android-intent, android-activity, android-fragments

Pretty new to android development, I need to know how I can change the size of my ListView in my fragment pragmatically to cover the entire screen? match_parent, fill_parent didn't work.

I have hard coded values of 500dp

Here is my fragment

```
<RelativeLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    tools:context=".MainActivity">

    <ListView
        android:id="@android:id/list"
        android:layout_width="500dp"
        android:layout_height="500dp"
        android:divider="@null"
        android:dividerHeight="0dp"
        android:layout_marginTop="0dp">
    </ListView>

</RelativeLayout>
```

and here is JAVA my fragment code:

```
import android.app.ListFragment;
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.util.DisplayMetrics;
import android.view.LayoutInflater;
import android.view.View;
import android.view.ViewGroup;
import android.widget.FrameLayout;
import android.widget.LinearLayout;
import android.widget.ListView;
import android.view.ViewGroup.LayoutParams;
import android.widget.LinearLayout;
import java.util.List;



public class MyFragment extends ListFragment {

    List<data> flowers = new datadata().getdatas();


    public MyFragment() {
    }

    @Override
    public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);


       dataArrayAdapter adapter = new dataArrayAdapter(getActivity(),
               R.layout.data_listitem,
               flowers);
       setListAdapter(adapter);


    }

    @Override
    public View onCreateView(LayoutInflater inflater,
                             ViewGroup container,
                             Bundle savedInstanceState) {

        View rootView = inflater.inflate(R.layout.my_fragment, container, false);

        return rootView;
    }

}
```

here is my main Activity class

```
<ScrollView  xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    android:id="@+id/myContainer"
    android:layout_width="fill_parent"
    android:layout_height="fill_parent"
    android:scrollbarStyle="insideOverlay"
    android:scrollbars="none"
    android:fadeScrollbars="true"
    android:fitsSystemWindows="true"
    android:layout_gravity="top"
    >
</ScrollView >
```

and this is my main activity java code:

```
package mshirvan.example.com.netplex;

import android.app.Activity;
import android.app.AlertDialog;
import android.app.Fragment;
import android.content.Intent;
import android.media.Image;
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.view.Menu;
import android.view.MenuItem;
import android.view.View;
import android.widget.AdapterView;
import android.widget.FrameLayout;
import android.widget.ImageView;
import android.widget.ListView;
import android.widget.RelativeLayout;
import android.widget.Toast;
import android.view.View.OnClickListener;

import data.row1;


public class MainActivity extends Activity {

    public static float screenx = 0;
    public static float screeny = 0;
    public static int screenpixelx = 0;
    public static int screenpixely = 0;


    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);

        ScreenUtility utility = new ScreenUtility(this);
        screenx = utility.getWidth();
        screeny = utility.getHeight();
        screenpixelx = utility.getPixelWidth();
        screenpixely = utility.getPixelHeight();

        MyFragment frag = new MyFragment();

        getFragmentManager().beginTransaction()
                .add(R.id.myContainer, frag)
                .commit();

    }

    @Override
    public boolean onCreateOptionsMenu(Menu menu) {
        // Inflate the menu; this adds items to the action bar if it is present.
        getMenuInflater().inflate(R.menu.main, menu);
        return true;
    }

    @Override
    public boolean onOptionsItemSelected(MenuItem item) {
        // Handle action bar item clicks here. The action bar will
        // automatically handle clicks on the Home/Up button, so long
        // as you specify a parent activity in AndroidManifest.xml.
        int id = item.getItemId();

        if (id == R.id.action_settings) {
            ScreenUtility utility = new ScreenUtility(this);
            String output = "Width: " + utility.getWidth() + ", " +
                    "Height: " + utility.getHeight();

            return true;
        }
        return super.onOptionsItemSelected(item);
    }
}
```

Comment: please post your activity code and layout

Comment: <ScrollView  xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    android:id="@+id/myContainer"
    android:layout_width="fill_parent"
    android:layout_height="fill_parent"
    android:scrollbarStyle="insideOverlay"
    android:scrollbars="none"
    android:fadeScrollbars="true"
    android:fitsSystemWindows="true"
    android:layout_gravity="top"
    >
</ScrollView >

Comment: are you adding fragment in ScrollView?
please edit your question and add your activity code with it's layout there.

Comment: yes, I ll add it righ now, mer30 :)

Comment: why are you using ScrollView for fragment container?

Comment: it is long story but trying to create both vertical and horizonal scrollable views

Comment: see my new answer. ;)

Answer (score 1):

Add the following to your fragment RelativeLayout. This should be as follows:

```
android:layout_width="match_parent"
android:layout_height="500dp"
```

For example the map layout fragment should be as follows :

```
<RelativeLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="500dp"
    android:paddingLeft="@dimen/activity_horizontal_margin"
    android:paddingRight="@dimen/activity_horizontal_margin"
    android:paddingTop="@dimen/activity_vertical_margin"
    android:paddingBottom="@dimen/activity_vertical_margin" tools:context=".MainActivity"
    >

    <com.google.android.gms.maps.MapView
        android:id="@+id/map"
        android:name="com.google.android.gms.maps.SupportMapFragment"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"
        android:layout_alignParentEnd="true"
        android:layout_alignParentTop="true" />

</RelativeLayout>
```

Then add this fragment layout in the main layout.

Answer (score 0):

put these in your listview too:

android:layout_width="match_parent"
 android:layout_height="match_parent"

or you can change the layoutparameters to match_parent in yout fragment 
that contains the listview.

Comment: I did and it didnt work :( is there a way doing it through the code?

Comment: @user1429595 there is, but you need to do it in the activity class. Could you please provide it?

Comment: yeah get a reference to your listview in oncreateview with findviewbyid() on your rootview and set its layoutparameters (check online)

Answer (score 0):

you have to set the fragment container height to match parent not ListView. in your case ,ListView will fill it's parent height. ListView's parent is RelativeLayout and the RelativeLayout height is matchParent that means , RelativeLayout will also fill it's container and it's container is your fragment place holder that defined in your activity's layout file. you have to set that container's height to matchParent.

Answer (score 0):

I think the problem is that you are trying to add fragment to `ScrollView`. use `FrameLayout` with `android:layout_height=match_parent` for fragment's container and if you have to add multiple fragments, then define multiple `FrameLayout`s in your activity's layout or add them dynamically.