# How to increase the height of list row using fragments?

Tags: java, android, listview

I am working with fragments and created simple basis list and everything is working fine. But there is one thing that I can't do my self. I want to increase the height of the each row to cover the most of screen of any device. I know how to do in activities but I am not familiar with fragments. Any one can find a way for me? 
[image: here is the Screen shot of my list]

Comment: what do you mean by increase in size. the number of items in the list or the display height of each row of the list.

Comment: height of each row. sorry if I didn't explain well

Comment: [possible duplicate](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/26937658/how-to-change-a-size-of-fragment?rq=1)

Comment: this is not the good idea. and also not working